# Divide-and-Conquer Algorithms: What exactly is $a$ and $b$ here?

Tags: algorithms, mergesort

Chapter **2.3.2 Analysing divide-and-conquer algorithms** of *Introduction to Algorithms*, fourth edition, by CLRS, says the following:

> A recurrence for the running time of a divide-and-conquer algorithm falls out from the three steps of the basic method. As we did for insertion sort, let $T(n)$ be the worst-case running time on a problem of size $n$. If the problem size is small enough, say $n < n_0$ for some constant $n_0 > 0$, the straightforward solution takes constant time, which we write as $\Theta(1)$. Suppose that the division of the problem yields $a$ subproblems, each with size $n/b$, that is, $1/b$ the size of the original. For merge sort, both $a$ and $b$ are $2$, but we'll see other divide-and-conquer algorithms in which $a \not= b$. It takes $T(n/b)$ time to solve one subproblem of size $n/b$, and so it takes $aT(n/b)$ time to solve all $a$ of them. If it takes $D(n)$ time to divide the problem into subproblems and $C(n)$ time to combine the solutions to the subproblems into the solution to the original problem, we get the recurrence
> $$T(n) = \begin{cases} \Theta(1) & \text{if} \ n < n_0, \\ D(n) + aT(n / b) + C(n) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

What exactly is $a$ and $b$ here? Based on this description, it seems to me that $b$ might be the branching factor, and $a$ might be something like the depth, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the runtime out of a recursion formula when using divide and conquer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/154210/how-to-find-the-runtime-out-of-a-recursion-formula-when-using-divide-and-conquer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, $a$ is the branching factor (the number of subproblems) and $n/b$ means that each subproblem has size $n/b$.

For example, if you do matrix multiplication with a recurrence relation of $T(n) \leq 7T(n/2) + n$, then you branch into 7 subproblems, each of size half.

Meaning that at depth $j$ in the recursion, you have $a^j$ many subproblems, each of size $n/b^j$.